# JSON Formatter for Eclipse

Tags: json, eclipse, formatter

I want to format the JSON files in my eclipse on save file action, based on number of spaces that i can configure. I tried using JSON Editor Plugin but it gave me null pointer exception on saving.

[image: Error on saving with Json Editor Plugin]
Then i tried JSON Tools plugin and it worked but it used a tab for formatting the lines.
Is there any hack that i can do with plugin jar to configure and change TAB to 4 spaces?
Are better json formatter available for eclipse?

Comment: This json plugin is great: https://github.com/boothen/Json-Eclipse-Plugin , you can also install it from Eclipse marketplace.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried **Json Tools for Eclipse**? It is handy and lightweight Eclipse plugin. I have checked this right now and it works as you want - if there are TABs in a modified JSON file, they are changed to 4 spaces.

You can find it in [Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/json-tools) or install it using update site:

```
https://bitbucket.org/denmiroch/jsontools/src/default/JsonSite/
```

Answer (score 5):

Some other extensions adhere to the preference set for the general text editor.

If it doesn't clash with other settings you can try:

General -> Appearance -> Editors -> Text Editors

[x] Insert spaces for tabs

Answer (score 2):

As of Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) a JSON Editor is included in the Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers.

Comment: Using the default Neon JSON editor, I can't get rid of the tabs (I only want spaces) despite hunting through the preferences dialog. Don't know which one the Neon default might be, but both the JSON Tools plugin and the JSON Editor plugin show as 'uninstalled' in my Neon market place.

Comment: For the record, the  JSON Editor plugin handles tab conversion to spaces.

Comment: How can I see the the structure of JSON object while defining in eclipse neon?

Comment: @shambhu open the Outline view to see the structure of your JSON. Window > Show View > Outline

Comment: @Adam In my Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0), you can indent JSON files in the "JSON Editor" with spaces instead of tabs. Goto Window > Preferences > JSON > JSON Files > Editor. Then under the Formatting section, toggle the "Indent using spaces" radio. You might want to adjust your "indentation size" too, e.g. to 2, 3, or 4 spaces.

Comment: As I did not have this feature (upgraded from previous eclipse versions) I had to get out to Marketplace and install: "Eclipse Web Developer Tools". Just adding that in case anyone else needs it.

Answer (score 0):

To change any file to open in default editor
Goto Eclipse Menu Window -> General -> Editors -> File Associations

You will see lots of **File Types** section available, Select the **file** in **File Types** Section, In **Associated editors** section you will find most available editors to open the file.

Select Any editor and click on **Default** button to open file in ***default editor*** window.

**Example View:**
[image: Eclipse File Associations]